# Error while applying lambda function while creating a new column in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
master_frame_venture['Revised Category List'] = master_frame_venture['category_list'].apply(lambda x: str(x).split('|')[0] if '|' in str(x))
```

It is giving the error "Invalid syntax"
What would be the correct one??

Comment: You need to add an `else ....`, though there are better ways to perform this calculation. See [mcve] for how to create a question that we can answer easily.

Comment: Please share a sample of your dataframe with the code, so that we can understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

You need an else:

```
master_frame_venture['Revised Category List'] = master_frame_venture['category_list'].apply(lambda x: x.split('|')[0] if '|' in x else x)
```